# Programmatically created Magento cart doesn't connect to customer

Tags: php, magento, cart

I'm trying to build a bridge between a third-party site and our Magento shop. A customer can build a cart on the other website, but then I have to re-create it once they get shuffled to our site.

Inside the controller:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton( 'checkout/session' )->getQuote();
$catalog = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' );

$cart = json_decode( $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'cart' ) );

foreach ($cart as $sku => $qty) {
    $product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $sku );
    $quote->addProduct( $product, $qty );
}

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

This appears to work. After creating the cart, I can check, and the quote appears to be created and populated:

```
echo $quote->getId() . '<br><br>';
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getProduct()->getName());
}
```

The issue is that is never gets attached to the user. So the second you move to another page, it forgets your cart altogether. I'm sure (I hope) this is something simple I am overlooking. I don't have a customer ID at this point because they haven't logged in yet. This is the first page that they would have seen.

Comment: In case it matters - I'm using Magento EE 1.14